# i need help to display the crystal report's sub report in correctly

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

i got this sub report and when more and more data needs to be display in the sub report it will display like this..this is the 1st page..
[image]

and this is the 2nd page..
[image]
why is this ? that all the data in the sub report jump in the 2nd page ? i want it to display in the 1st page and the extra data will then be display in the 2nd page..glad with any help :)

Comment: What does the designer look like? Where is the sub report located in the designer? Check the settings in the Section Expert.

Comment: i put the sub report in the details section..sir..

Comment: where you place fields in sub report and also looks like page 1 is coming from different section and page 2 is coming from different section can you show the design of the sub report?

Comment: i already figure this out..i just uncheck the keep together in the properties of the sub-report :)